# How to use csrf if using django just as REST API without frontend

Tags: django

I am currently using Django only as an API that contains no templates or HTML (frontend is on other server), it is just used to be requested. How do I enable csrf protection for POST requests if I don't have access to the csrf?

Comment: csrf probably still comes in the header of the request, but if you are sure you don't have access to it, than you cannot protect it using csrf methods